# ImportError: cannot import name 'inception_preprocessing' from 'preprocessing'

Tags: python

the error message in the title occurred when i was trying to run the inception v3 model. I just did `pip install preprocessing` and used `from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing` but it popped out the error in the title:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'inception_preprocessing' from 'preprocessing' (/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/preprocessing/__init__.py)
```

Comment: There is no mention of `inception_preprocessing` in pip's version of preprocessing, are you sure you downloaded the right package?

Comment: This is the actual library installed when pip installing `preprocessing` and it does indeed not have `inception_preprocessing`. https://github.com/SpotlightData/preprocessing

Comment: It looks like this is what you're after https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/preprocessing/inception_preprocessing.py so you want to look up installing Tensorflow (and the parts of it you need)